# Hide password text

Tags: c#, winforms, password-protection

I have a textbox using UseSystemPasswordChar, so it will not display the password that the user enters. The issue is that the password is still able to be read by something like Spy++. I'm looking for a way to hide this like they do in the password fields in the Services.msc > Log On tab.

Comment: You could build up your own Textbox-Control which is derived from the Standard-Textbox. If there is an input in the textwindow you can write a dummy-value to the output and save the correct input in a property.

Comment: You use winforms or asp or...?

Comment: I'm using WinForms for this application.

Comment: if you're using WinForms I seriously wonder why you'd want to write a special control for hiding the value from e.g. Spy++. It's the user itself who'll use the Spyprogram to look at the value they just entered. They already know what value they keyed in.. keying being the prime concern here - if you're worried about password stealing try to find a way for keyloggers to ignore the typed phrase..

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I've got so far.

You can improve this by having some unique events to indicate whether a pressed key has been accepted, if InputFilter or RealText has been changed, etc...

Another great thing to improve would be the default usage of InputFilter, because working with char and Keys doesn't really work for many special keys. For example - at the moment, if you press Alt+F4 when the PasswordBox is in focus, it will type in 's'... So there's a bag of bugs to fix.

And lastly, there's probably a more elegant way to handle capital vs non-capital letters input than what I did there.

So here it is:

```
public class PasswordBox : TextBox
{
    private string _realText;

    public string RealText
    {
        get { return this._realText; }
        set
        {
            var i = this.SelectionStart;

            this._realText = value ?? "";

            this.Text = "";
            this.Text = new string('*', this._realText.Length);

            this.SelectionStart = i > this.Text.Length ? this.Text.Length : i;
        }
    }

    private Func<KeyEventArgs, bool> _inputFilter;

    public Func<KeyEventArgs, bool> InputFilter
    {
        get { return this._inputFilter; }
        set { this._inputFilter = value ?? (e => true); }
    }

    public PasswordBox()
    {
        this.RealText = "";
        this.InputFilter = e => "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789".Any(c => c == e.KeyValue);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Back:
                if (this.SelectionStart > 0 || this.SelectionLength > 0)
                {
                    this.RealText = this.SelectionLength == 0
                                        ? this.RealText.Remove(--this.SelectionStart, 1)
                                        : this.RealText.Remove(this.SelectionStart, this.SelectionLength);
                }
                break;
            case Keys.Delete:
                if (this.SelectionStart == this.TextLength)
                {
                    return;
                }

                this.RealText = this.RealText.Remove(this.SelectionStart, this.SelectionLength == 0 ? 1 : this.SelectionLength);
                break;
            case Keys.X:
            case Keys.C:
            case Keys.V:
                if (e.Control)
                {
                    return;
                }
                goto default;
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Shift:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
                base.OnKeyDown(e);
                break;
            default:
                if (e.Control)
                {
                    e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
                    base.OnKeyDown(e);
                    break;
                }

                if (this.InputFilter(e))
                {
                    var c = (char)e.KeyValue;

                    if (e.Shift == IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
                    {
                        c = char.ToLower(c);
                    }

                    this.RealText = this.RealText.Remove(this.SelectionStart, this.SelectionLength)
                        .Insert(this.SelectionStart, c.ToString());

                    this.SelectionStart++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So try something like this

```
        private string realpass = "";
        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (Char) Keys.Back)
                realpass += realpass.Substring(0, realpass.Length - 2);
            realpass += e.KeyChar.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < realpass.Length; i++)
                textBox1.Text += "*";
        }
```

Comment: Here i implement only 'backspace', so you should to implement other buttons like 'del' etc.

Comment: Yes, but it just example how he can solve problem, i will not implement all code.

Comment: If you're keeping the password in memory, you might consider using [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) instead of a plain string for extra security (against memory dumps), however that makes the handling of the password-string a little more complicated.

Comment: Instead of setting `textBox1.Text` in a loop, you could do: `textBox1.Text = new String('*', realpass.Length);`

Answer (score 1):

You should not use your own dialog if you intend to collect Windows/domain user credentials. You should use what Windows provides via PInvoke or simply use a wrapper like this,

http://weblogs.asp.net/hernandl/archive/2005/11/21/usercredentialsdialog.aspx

and this,

http://credentials.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1: This is pretty nice, why reinvent, particularly in the security realm. Actually, you can/should use it for non-Windows credentials (using the CREDUI_FLAGS_GENERIC_CREDENTIALS or the respective option of the Credentials CodePlex project).

Comment: @Anton, I am wondering why it does not connect to the question?

Comment: @Lex Li The question is about general password and you're proposing solution for Windows\domain credentials (By the way, may be it should be moved to topic in the Community wiki).

Comment: As @Christian.K pointed out, it also works for generic credentials, so it is not for Windows credentials only. (Unless this project is going to be ported to Mono and other platforms that you need to invoke native API other than Win32.)